# Connect to Firebase

Tags: android-studio, firebase

Пытаюсь подключиться к firebase через android studio, но выходит данная ошибка:

> No clients were able to be added to your Firebase project for the
>   following reasons: An app with this package name and SHA1 is already
>   connected to a Google project. If you have used a Google API
>   previously, please select that project in the Connect to an existing
>   project list.

Никакие манипуляции не помогают. Проект уже опубликован в Google Play. Владелец я.

Comment: Вам надо через браузер зайти в консоль Firebase и подтянуть туда проекты из google Play

Comment: @rjhdby, связал аккаунт firebase с google play(автоматически связал приложение), но ошибка все равно появляется

Comment: Насколько я понимаю ситуацию, Android Studio ломится к Firebase с вашим debug сертификатом, который конфликтует с девелоперским, поскольку аппа уже опубликована. Ппопробуйте подложить свой девелоперский сертификат.

Answer (score 0):

Предположительно во время разработки вы уже пытались подключить firebase, там остались данные о проекте с таким же API, вам необходимо зайти в вашу [консоль](https://console.firebase.google.com) и удалить от туда приложение подключенное к проекту, после чего вновь попробовать подключить Проект.

Comment: В консоле удалял все проекты, все равно выдает ошибку, других аккаунтов нет

Comment: подключите API вручную

Comment: Вы имеете в виду скачиванием json файла и вручную добавить в проект? А так не будет каких-нибудь проблем?

Comment: Все вписывать вручную на сайте, а не автоматически